# Hwo to trim email addresses in Exim?

Tags: email-server, exim

I have a list of emails from client accounts that are built like this: `name+somegiberish@gmail.com`

I have tied looking into configs but haven't found such an option.

How do i trim in Exim those emails? I want Exim to remove data from `"+"` to `"@"` and use that email address to send.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What kind of problem is it causing you to use the addresses exactly as given by your clients? Did you discuss with your clients whether it is ok with them to drop the "plus" suffix from their addresses? And why do you want to do it in Exim, instead of fixing your address list?

Comment: I want to have both solutions, both for the backend and for Exim. is it relevant why?

Comment: Actually yes. Doing it in Exim is such a serious violation of Internet standards that you'd need a very good reason for doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't.**

For domains *you control* (but I am assuming you do not control `gmail.com`) you may use the facilities of your mail servers to add special meaning to the plus sign. Commonly but not ubiquitously, the *first* occurrence of the `+` sign is used to separate a *localpart* address extension, meaning all mailboxes with matching pre-delimiter name are treated the same.

But for domains *outside your control*, **you are not to make any assumptions about their structure**, you take the address string, and you only *encode* it as each respective protocol demands, you never change it. A mail provider may arbitrarily assign different meanings or no meaning at all to the plus sign. **The address with such assumed extension stripped could be owned by the same, a different party, or not valid altogether.**

Just like you would not change letter case, "fix" typos or write out abbreviated names, you do not modify 3rd-party-provided addresses. Use them as provided, that is the only likely valid version of them.